# Submit form with a different encoding

Tags: html, forms, character-encoding, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have a page which needs to redirect a user to another separate system (I have no access there). The system requires some parameters to be sent to it via POST (for example "userId"). The problem is, that my page is in UTF-8 and the other system's encoding is ISO-8859-1.

Also, it could take some time to process the request for the other system. That's why while the request is processing, user should be seeing some "Please wait, you are being processed by the system" in my page.

The best way how I'd like it to look is something like this:

1. User opens page A and presses
   "Send me to System".
2. User is
   shown a page with text "Please wait,
   you are being processed by the
   system". Also there's hidden POST
   form on the same page that is being
   posted after 1 second with
   Javascript.
3. When the other server
   finishes processing the request,
   user finally receives the response
   and my text is replaced with a
   different page provided by the other
   server.

The problem is, I can not make a form as it will post the data in UTF-8 and the other server will try to parse it as ISO-8859-1.

What are the possible solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Comment: Java, but I really do not think that matters, as the problem is happening on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to make it using iframes. Iframe can have it's personal encoding loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just make the form page only use ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Comment: I can't. It uses lots of UTF characters.

Comment: Use your imagination, try an iframe, a popup window, have a warning page that drops all the clutter before redirecting to a plain form, etc.